# Azure Dev Ops - Project rename by who

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Someone in my team rename one of our project in Azure Dev Ops.

Is there any way to know who did that ( we asked everyone and no one said he did it ) ? We got an automatic email about it but we don't have any information about who and why it was changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see who renamed the project in Organization settings >> [Auditing log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) if your organization has connected to AAD. Here is detailed [auditing action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/auditing-events?view=azure-devops#project) for project.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it was not activated but thanks a lot for the answer !